# Mysql trigger fails when including last 16 of 448 rows to update

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a table of 448 rows, each comprised of dates, and each time a date is updated, a trigger sends the old date to a table corresponding to that assigned row name, after updating the date on the main DB table of 448 rows. This works with one strange hitch: There are 56 sets of 8 rows, and whenever I include the last TWO sets in the trigger, or one row over the 432, the trigger fails. The purpose of the main table is to contain all the most recent dates of a particular, pre-assigned incident, and I wanted to keep the old dates by sending them to its corresponding archive table in an AFTER/UPDATE fashion. Whenever I include ANY of the last two sets, nothing is updated on the main table anyhow so no dates are sent via trigger to the archive tables. However, if I only include 432 of the rows to send to their corresponding table of the same name, it works! Wow! At first I thought it may have been too many lines in the trigger, but re-authoring the trigger backwards, or arranging the row declarations arbitrarily, made no difference. Including the last two sets of 8 somehow renders the trigger ineffective, to the point that the main table cannot be updated. 
The project is structured this way:
I have a main view date table with 56 rows and 8 columns of dates with an "UPDATE" button that links to the EDIT version. This edit version has inputs that contain the corresponding dates from the DB, which is editable/updateable by using Datepickr. The trigger is structured like this:

```
begin
if NEW.b1psp <> OLD.b1psp then
insert into b1psp (logDate, b1psp) values (now(), OLD.b1psp);
end if;
if NEW.b1ptp <> OLD.b1ptp then
insert into b1ptp (logDate, b1ptp) values (now(), OLD.b1ptp);
end if;
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
if NEW.b2psp <> OLD.b2psp then
insert into b2psp (logDate, b2psp) values (now(), OLD.b2psp);
end if;
..........
(and so on)
end
```

The "b1psp" is a name given to one of the rows, and each row has its own unique name like that. "b1" is a prefix used 8 times, and "b2" as well, and so on..
There are 448 of these, and the trigger works until I include one over 432. Can anyone help explain this behavior? Without the trigger, or at least with trigger that covers the updates of 432 rows, the table can be updated with no problem while updating the auxiliary tables as well. I am at a complete loss to explain this.

Comment: do `describe information_schemas.TRIGGERS`, and look for the `ACTION_STATEMENT` field. That field's type will be the limit on how long a trigger's "body" can be.

Comment: In the SQL query box? Didn't work... MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'information_schemas.triggers' doesn't exist